# Migrating complex SVN repository to GIT

Tags: git, svn, github, git-svn

I have a SVN Repository with more than 100 projects and I want to migrate to GIT now. This is how the SVN Repository looks like:

```
customer_1/prj_1 (trunk, branches, tags)
customer_1/prj_2 (trunk, branches, tags)
customer_1/prj_n (trunk, branches, tags)
...
customer_2/prj_1 (trunk, branches, tags)
customer_2/prj_2 (trunk, branches, tags)
customer_2/prj_n (trunk, branches, tags)
...
customer_n/prj_1 (trunk, branches, tags)
customer_n/prj_2 (trunk, branches, tags)
customer_n/prj_n (trunk, branches, tags)
```

Via SVN I can checkout:

1. The entire repository containing all customers and all projects
2. All projects of a single customer
3. A specific customer's project

I still need these three ways of access using GIT, especially branching and tagging single customer projects and not only the entire repository. So basically in SVN different customer projects have different stable releases being stored in the "tags" directory for each project. I need to differentiate between customer project releases in GIT as well.

I have converted the SVN Repository to a single GIT Repository (using svn-git), but as (I think) GIT does not allow to clone single folders like Subversion, it needs to be structured now by using submodules or subtrees.

Is it necessary to create a single GIT repository for every single customer project (which would take a lot of time) or what is the most common way to achieve what I was asking for?

Comment: Are e.g. all prj_1 identical across customers (modulo minor modifications)? In that case you would probably to model them as different branches in the same repository. Otherwise what's the problem with having many small repositories for each project? You can still keep the folder structure for different customers, but it wouldn't be directly coupled to version control anymore (which makes sense to me).

Comment: I had one big and central repository in Subversion on a webserver, which I simply could browse with a webbrowser, seing all customer projects, so I only needed to know one repository URL. But if I have single repositories, one for each project, I have to use more than a hundred URLs. What I need is a central access point to all GIT repositories like "http://git.domain.com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to tag individual customer projects, then you need one git repository per project. Tags (and branches) in git are global to their repository, there is no way to tag a subdirectory.

To do this using `git-svn`, run

```
git svn clone -s http://svn-repo/customer_1/prj_1 
git svn clone -s http://svn-repo/customer_1/prj_2
```

etc.

This may indeed take a while, but you'll probably have to live with that. You would of course script the calls to git-svn.

As to browsing the repositories:

If you have multiple git repos, you can just check them out as subfolders in one folder. If you want to browse them on the server, without cloning/checking out, you will need to install a git repository browser. There are many available - there's a list in the git wiki: [Interfaces, frontends, and tools](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools).

Comment: O.k, I kinda thought I would need that. But how can I globally browse the repositories for customer projects via GIT?

Comment: @Hackse: You can't browse via git, but you can do it in SVN.

Comment: I am looking for a GIT-only solution without SVN. I am wondering how big companies are handling several GIT repositories at once. In Subversion you have one access point to all projects in one single repository like "http://svn.domain.com", because they are just folders in the same repository.

Comment: @Hackse: Ah, I see, you want to browse after converting - I though you wanted to browse using `git-svn`. I updated my answer.

Comment: I'm using subtrees for including subprojects and gitweb for online browsing. Thanks.